# Any way for starting a Fiori App via a SAP GUI Transaction?

Tags: sap-fiori, sap-gui

I'm wondering if I can open a Fiori App (by Transaction Code `LPD_CUST`) from SAP GUI (via a transaction code). So far I think I can somehow achieve that by building a program which open a web browser to access the app's URL. Are there any better way to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, but as you said it needs little coding.

Step 1. Create a class and method. In the method have a simple code as below.

```
DATA: lv_url type string.

ld_url = '<Direct URL to your Fiori App>'.

CALL FUNCTION 'CALL_BROWSER'
 EXPORTING
url = lv_url.
```

Step 2. SE93 -> Create a Transaction -> Start Object as 'Method of a class'. Mention the above class and method.